# How do I install the latest Unity3D beta?

Tags: software-installation, unity3d

I am trying to install Unity 3D on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. The forum links to a latest release file but the problem is the file is only 273KB. It gives me a file called "UnitySetup-2018.1.0b13" and I have no idea on how to open it. How do I install it?

[image: Photo of the forum link]
<sup>**Photo of the forum link**</sup>

[image: Photo of the link to download the file]
<sup>**Photo of the link to download the file**</sup>

[image: The file]
<sup>**The file**</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to follow the instructions given further up the page:

```
Make the installer writeable: chmod +x UnitySetup-2017.3.0f1
Run it: ./UnitySetup-2017.3.0f1 --unattended --install-location=(path)
```